# Using classes in Java (beginner)

Tags: java, class

I am currently trying to create a class that prints out a rectangle with a height and width 1. I have the program set up (there is a template we are supposed to use) and I incorporated all of the steps. However there is one problem with the return statement on the line "SimpleRectangle(){" it says it is missing a return statement but no matter what I return it still comes up with an error.

```
 public static void main (String[] args){  
  SimpleRectangle rectangle1=new SimpleRectangle();
    System.out.println("The area of radius "+rectangle1.perimeter+" is  "+rectangle1.getArea());
 }
 double height;
 double width;

 SimpleRectangle(){
  height=1;
  width=1;
 }

 double getArea(){
  return height*width;
 }

 double getPerimeter(){
  return length+length+width+width;
 }
}
```

Comment: why do you post incomplete code? This doesn't even remotely compile.

Comment: @wero but it does, I'm just missing one return statement

Comment: For example it is missing class name definition...

Comment: If its missing a return statement then it does not, in fact, compile.

Comment: @PetterFriberg exactly, and I bet that it is not "class SimpleRectangle" which explains the error

Comment: Well I'm sorry I used what my professor asked us to and it was messed up...It has happened many times before in the class which is why people always have problems

Comment: @DarianLee look at the code you posted, there must be something before `public static void main` which you forgot to include in your post

Comment: Yeah, public class Lab_9_1

Comment: @DarianLee please edit your post and add this information

Answer (score 2):

This looks like a constructor for a class called `SimpleRectange`

```
SimpleRectangle(){
  height=1;
  width=1;
}
```

In the code you provide there doesn't seem to be such a class. Make sure your code is included in a class with that name and that it has all the fields you are accessing e.g.

```
public class SimpleRectangle {
    double height;
    double width;
    double perimeter;
    double length;

    public static void main(String[] args) {

    ...
    ...
}
```

If your code is in a class with any other name you will get "Invalid method declaration. Return type required"

Comment: don't make perimeter an attribute. you can calculate that.

Comment: If it's up to me I would make it a `private final` field along with all other fields and calculate it in the constructor. This way it's only calculated once and `getPerimeter`, that may get called many times, will just return it.

Comment: private final? what if the width changes and the height stays the same? don't create attributes that depend on each other!!!

Comment: I got the functional virus recently and I try to make all classes immutable. There are advantages to that. If there is good reason for this class to be mutable a developer has to consider what fields change more often and who makes the changes. Calculating the perimeter each time the getter is called is a legitimate option if all other fields change often.

Comment: we're talking about java here. remember that. java is not fast, java is not functional.

Comment: Languages are not fast or slow. The JVM does an excellent job with performance albeit not always as good a C++ compiler. What I am doing is called minimizing mutability. It's Item 15 in "Effective Java" where you can see many good arguments about it.

Answer (score 1):

`rectangle1.perimeter` should be `rectangle1.getPerimeter()`

also you dont have a field called length. it's called height

```
 double getPerimeter(){
     return height+height+width+width;
 }
```

the consturctor need to be public

```
public SimpleRectangle(){
    height=1;
    width=1;
}
```

Comment: thanks, but there is still an error message for the return statement

Comment: error: invalid method declaration; return type required
   SimpleRectangle(){
   ^
1 error

Comment: In your method `getPerimeter()` you are using `length` instead of `height`.

Comment: @Patrick I already fixed all of that, just haven't updated it on the page yet

Answer (score 1):

`rectangle1.perimeter` is not working because there is no field defined with that name, instead you have a method , therefore you need to call it

this is wrong, you need to do `rectangle1.getPerimeter()`

Answer (score 1):

You have several issues with your code it **is not compiling**

The current error is related to missing class definition, but there will  be others.......

Try to not copy and past but to understand what you where missing, **class definition**, no field declaration for **length**, wrong call to method ecc.

I have included some public and private declaration I suggest that you study some also what this means...

**AND NR 1 TRY TO USE AND IDE AS ECLIPSE, THIS WILL HELP YOU ENORMOUSLY AVOIDING AL OF THESE PROBLEMS AND WHEN YOU LEARN TO DEBUG YOU BECOME A PROGRAMMER.**, no need for SO, for debugging problems

```
public class SimpleRectangle {

    private double height;
    private double width;

    public SimpleRectangle() {
        this.height = 1;
        this.width = 1;
    }

    public double getArea() {
        return height * width;
    }

    public double getPerimeter() {
        return height + height + width + width;
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SimpleRectangle rectangle1 = new SimpleRectangle();
        System.out.println("The area of radius " + rectangle1.getPerimeter() + " is  " + rectangle1.getArea());
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

In order to use `rectangle1.getPerimeter()` or `rectangle1.getArea()`, you need to create a class that looks something like this:

```
public class SimpleRectangle {

    double height;
    double width;

    SimpleRectangle() {
        height = 1;
        width = 1;
    }

    double getArea() {
        return height * width;
    }

    double getPerimeter() {
        return 2 * (height + width);
    }

}
```

Then you need to create the object (as shown below) before you can use `rectangle1.getPerimeter()`:

```
public class MainClass {

    public static void main (String[] args) {
        SimpleRectangle rectangle1 = new SimpleRectangle();

        System.out.println("The area of radius " + rectangle1.getPerimeter() + " is " + rectangle1.getArea());

    }

}
```